# Internet Explorer 10 aborting some stylesheets

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Strange problem exhibited only with IE10 on Windows 8. No other IE version, no other OS version.

Some stylesheets are aborted, apparently in transport, intermittently.

This seems to happen when there are three `<link>` tags in sequence. The tags are correctly specified and are being served from Amazon S3 over HTTPS. The first two items abort when (or prior to) loading. Altering the order of the items appears to make the first two items abort in all cases.

This problem is intermittent, and different people can reproduce with differing success.

I have seen a lot of conjecture about this on the web but no solution.

Comment: Why use 3 style sheets? Why not combine the style sheets into one file - this would fix the problem if it is only occurring when there are three <link> tags in sequence.

Comment: Why assume I am able to control the selection of stylesheets? I'm not going to re-write vast chunks of code just to fix a bug in IE (unless I really need to).

Comment: True.. and from what I read, you only have this problem with the Win8/IE10 user base. I was thinking you had three random style sheets you could join together easily. Just trying to help :)

Comment: Sadly life's not that simple! Yes, it is only for a very specific set of clients.

Comment: "I'm not going to re-write vast chunks of code just to fix a bug in IE" - Why not? Everyone else does. :)

Comment: Because I don't know what the bug is. I can't justify spending days of effort on something I can't even reproduce reliably! For starters, no way to test that it's fixed.

Comment: What about using @import you could keep the sheets separate and load them with an    arbitrary file to join them...just a suggestion

Comment: It's interesting you say IE10 and Win 8... Does it persist on Win8.1 and IE11.  What are the error codes shown in the developer tools for the netowrk connections?

Comment: Sorry this was a long time ago! I don't have any more information and the project's over.

Comment: First, I would suggest you make sure it's not a server problem by serving the same page, with the same resources from another server with different technology. It could be a headers problem (Content-Security-Policy for example) or some other server-related issue.

Comment: And you may need to post a link to the page, in the comments, if you can. People will be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanks Osvaldo, but as I said, this project is long gone!

Answer (score 1):

I would try opening the stylesheets and and the page linking them in Notepad++. Then do a find and make sure all carriage returns are either just `\n`, or just `\r\n`, not a Mix of both.

You can do this in Notepad++ by going to *Edit -> EOL Conversion* and then pick Windows format or Unix format. To see if there is a mixture. Confirm they are mixed by going into Find, selecting extended search mode, and look for "`\r\n\0`".

If some end in `\r\n\0` and some just `\n\0`, maybe it confuses IE10 since it's a Microsoft product. Long shot, but give it a try.

Comment: Serious? Can you provide a reference for that?